# Change ListView's GridLine Color

Tags: c#, listview

Well i am trying to change the ListView's gridline color but i can't find any property that provide such think... Also i tried `DrawSubItem` with no luck.

#### Code

```
if ((e.ItemState & ListViewItemStates.Selected) > 0)
{
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Highlight, e.Bounds);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(e.SubItem.Text, listView1.Font,
    SystemBrushes.HighlightText, e.Bounds);
}
else
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString(e.SubItem.Text, listView1.Font,
    SystemBrushes.ControlText, e.Bounds);
}
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, e.Bounds);
```

However the GridLines still white as you see in the picture below!.

[image]

So how could i change those GridLines' Colors... so i don't have such bad contrast ?

Comment: you will have to override the onpaint event

Comment: By the way why not change to gridview? You can change the color there and it has lots of more functionality as well.

Comment: So something like [this](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#how-do-i-put-a-real-background-image-onto-an-objectlistview). However, this uses a custom ObjectListView, not a default ListView (which I suggest you use anyways)

Comment: @EhsanUllah : so what ?

Comment: so what means? asking me for something? If yes i am sorry i didn't understand,

Comment: @EhsanUllah : you said that i have to override the paint event but you didn't give any details about what to do next!?

Comment: @RuneS why not GridView instead of ListView? any specific reason for using Listview?

Comment: @EhsanUllah : it does not suites the overall look of my application... i don't wanna excel like list

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing ListView Header and Grid Lines colors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283781/changing-listview-header-and-grid-lines-colors)